# gaierror socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed mail.send(msg)

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to send email with flask_email and I get this error: gaierror socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed mail.send(msg)`

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smpt.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT']=465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']= "micorreo@runchet.com"
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']= "miclave"
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True

mail = Mail()

@app.route("/home", methods= ["POST", "GET"])
@app.route('/', methods= ["POST", "GET"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":        
        msg = Message("hi!",
                      sender="micorreo@runchet.com",
                    recipients =['testEmail@gmail.com'])
                        
        msg.body = "testing"
        mail.send(msg)
        return "send email."
    
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mail.init_app(app)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use your correct email username and password. Also please post the code rather it's images.

Comment: the mail and the user are an example are not the real ones.

Comment: I am trying to send an email using flask, with the flask_email module. When running the program I get this error: gaierror socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed mail.send(msg)

Answer (score 0):

`gaierror` means DNS resolution error, and in your case it probably means that the hostname does not exist. I'm not sure this is the problem, but my best guess is that this is due to a typo on line 6. You have:

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smpt.gmail.com'
```

Notice that `smpt` does not exist under the domain. Did you mean `smtp.gmail.com`?